# Convert object item to string

Tags: php, string, object

Saw this question has been asked many times, but somehow I can't get any of the solutions offered to work.

I'm calling an external API and the data is returned in the $infos object. I know how to address the values I need, but I can't seem to convert them into a string.

```
printf("<br>Last Connection = %s\n", $infos->network->last_connection);
$lastConn = print_r( $info->network->last_connection, true);
printf("<br>Last Connection is : %s\n", $lastConn);
```

Output:

```
Last Connection = 2015-01-27 17:47:39 
Last Connection is :
```

I tried print_r, var_dump, toString() but never get the output I want.

Comment: Do a `print_r` on `$lastConn` and see what it is.

Comment: There is a type in the line with print_r: *info* instead of *infos*

Comment: Oh damn.... you're right. After the typo fix, it worked. Can we get this post removed from all of the interwebs? :-( :-(

(But seriously, shoud I remove this post?)

Answer (score 0):

```
`(string)$myObject;`
```

or

`echo $myObject;`

```
$myObject = echo $myObject;
```

Don't work ?

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo. INFO instead of INFOS.